vscode markdown/mathjax renderer - difference between $ and $$?
Many websites use $$...$$ and disable $...$ for Markdown/Mathjax inline equations. For example, when writing README.md on GitHub, inline $$...$$ would be automatically interpreted as an inline equation. I'm writing an al-folio webpage, and $...$ is banned.
Is there a way (extension) to let vscode to render inline $$...$$ in markdown as inline equations? Whenever $$...$$ appears, the vscode default markdown renderer creates a new line.
